# Unable to get data through database into jasper report

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, jasper-reports

I made a spring boot program to get customized data into jasper report but every time I am generating pdf its giving me null and report is unable to create

Service class

```
@Service
public class ViolationService {

    @Autowired
    private ViolationRepository violationRepo;

    public List<Object> getViolation() {

        return violationRepo.findCustomAll();
    }
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface ViolationRepository extends JpaRepository<Violation, Long>{
    
    @Query(value = "SELECT violation_id,is_challan_generated,speed,vehicle_no,violation_type FROM violations", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Object> findCustomAll();

}
```

My jasper file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.17.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.17.0-6d93193241dd8cc42629e188b94f9e0bc5722efd  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="ViolationReport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="13b40567-32d6-4143-8ede-833a9454093f">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="172 Data Adapter (3)"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="Dataset1" uuid="83b92dde-2565-4eb4-97be-ee0708ab37d8">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="172 Data Adapter (3)"/>
        <queryString language="SQL">
            <![CDATA[select  * from etmcs_main.violations limit 20]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="violation_id" class="java.lang.Long">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="violation_id"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="violation_id"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="violations"/>
        </field>
        <field name="is_challan_generated" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="is_challan_generated"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="is_challan_generated"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="violations"/>
        </field>
        <field name="speed" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="speed"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="speed"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="violations"/>
        </field>
        <field name="vehicle_no" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="vehicle_no"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="vehicle_no"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="violations"/>
        </field>
        <field name="violation_type" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="violation_type"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="violation_type"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="violations"/>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select * from etmcs_main.violations limit 20]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="100" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="100" uuid="11a34e64-1a50-4304-bdf3-f0e8dc351678"/>
                <image scaleImage="FillFrame">
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="60" uuid="22282bd9-b33b-4ec2-ba64-dc2eb62d3353"/>
                    <imageExpression><![CDATA["https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.ce7ed7109a6b9593dd5225accb44ac5c?rik=BvBGBSSC9cU0Ag&riu=http%3a%2f%2fwww.aabmatica.com%2fimages-ABB-MATICA%2fAAB-logo.png&ehk=ZVpdbGIqxKxgUhcZ33Quvm2rOFooOsNoLA56uIuOn6s%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0"]]></imageExpression>
                </image>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="220" y="0" width="99" height="50" uuid="5c7c1ce6-c336-4cec-8492-d486e27c1d6e"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Violation Report]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="294" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="294" uuid="6e2f1a55-3f42-4d34-8c29-99d88dd0dc1b">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table_TH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table_CH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table_TD"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset1" uuid="859f352a-05cc-4201-a43a-194cd745fa31">
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="60" uuid="fe4aa254-6483-4ec2-bf3b-745d526785bc">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="30" uuid="39711e37-3295-4fc4-90ea-8fc972123bf3"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[violation_id]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="30" uuid="894df73d-510e-4a6a-841a-086bb135f12c"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{violation_id}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="80" uuid="e805f4f8-8c88-4377-ada7-5dbbd4859a41">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="e4216f73-99c2-4cd1-9823-7b79aa9a65dd"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[is_challan_generated]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="8a606ee7-2bf0-484b-bc2e-eb400333feb2"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{is_challan_generated}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="70" uuid="2c1d40a9-80a3-4d17-a996-a45ea137a7d2">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="70" height="30" uuid="6425b18c-ec22-424e-9158-acfc7455dc95"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[speed]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="70" height="30" uuid="cfd150e0-78c5-4290-a476-fb150d6ceef6"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{speed}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="70" uuid="77706ee6-61c3-4062-82db-cf20d53284e9">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="70" height="30" uuid="a5a2b546-ef9d-40f6-b969-20b734b96af9"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[vehicle_no]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="70" height="30" uuid="85cdbab1-3260-447c-871a-703a533be813"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{vehicle_no}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="70" uuid="df5113f9-8aaf-4b18-b02a-4235e8b1d7aa">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="70" height="30" uuid="60ebefcd-6036-4561-89ea-a185dec3fae0"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[violation_type]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="70" height="30" uuid="519a8b1d-2297-4e12-a6d1-eb77dcf13815"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{violation_type}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Controller Class

```
@RequestMapping( "/pdf")

    public void getReportsinPDF(HttpServletResponse response) throws JRException, IOException {

        // Compiled report
        InputStream jasperStream = (InputStream) this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/ViolationReport.jasper");
        
        // Adding attribute names
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("violation_id", violationModel.getViolation_id());
        params.put("is_challan_generated", violationModel.getIs_challan_generated());
        params.put("speed", violationModel.getSpeed());
        params.put("vehicle_no", violationModel.getVehicle_no());
        params.put("violation_type", violationModel.getViolation_type());
        
        
    
        
        // Fetching the student from the data database.
        final JRBeanCollectionDataSource source = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(violationnService.getViolation());

        JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(jasperStream);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, source);

        response.setContentType("application/x-pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=ViolationList.pdf");

        final ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, outStream);
    }
```

This is my entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "violations")
public class Violation {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "violation_id")
    private long violation_id;

    @Column(name = "transit_id")
    private long transit_id;

    public long getViolation_id() {
        return violation_id;
    }

    public void setViolation_id(long violation_id) {
        this.violation_id = violation_id;
    }

    @Column(name = "vehicle_no", length = 15)
    private String vehicle_no;

    @Column(name = "violation_type", length = 25)
    private String violation_type;

    @Column(name = "timestamp")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", timezone = "Asia/Kolkata")
    private Timestamp timestamp;

    @Column(name = "entry_timestamp")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", timezone = "Asia/Kolkata")
    private Timestamp entry_timestamp;

    @Column(name = "num_images", length = 2)
    private Integer num_images;

    @Column(name = "image_type", length = 5)
    private String image_type;

    @Column(name = "device_serial", length = 30)
    private String device_serial;

    @Column(name = "status", length = 2)
    private Integer status; // 0=Unverified, 1=verified, 2=Invalid

    @Column(name = "speed_limit", length = 3)
    private Integer speed_limit;

    @Column(name = "speed", length = 3)
    private Integer speed;

    @Column(name = "gate_id", length = 3)
    private Integer gate_id;

    @Column(name = "server_id", length = 2)
    private Integer server_id;

    @Column(name = "vehicle_class", length = 10)
    private String vehicle_class;

    public String getVehicle_class() {
        return vehicle_class;
    }

    public void setVehicle_class(String vehicle_class) {
        this.vehicle_class = vehicle_class;
    }

    @Column(name = "gate_name", length = 70, nullable=false)
    private String gate_name;

    @Column(name = "lane", length = 6)
    private String lane;

    // For getting image




    @Column(name = "exported", length = 2)
    private int exported;

    @Column(name = "latitude")
    private double latitude;

    public double getVlength() {
        return vlength;
    }

    public void setVlength(double vlength) {
        this.vlength = vlength;
    }

    @Column(name = "longitude")
    private double longitude;

    @Column(name = "vlength")
    private double vlength;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    
    @Column(name="dg_code")
    private String dg_code;

    @Column(name="color",length = 20)
    private String color;

    @Column(name = "lane_name", length = 50)
    private String lane_name;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long user_id;

    @Column(name="made", length = 50)
    private String made;

    @Column(name = "model",length = 50)
    private String model;

    @Column(name = "is_challan_generated", length = 2)
    private int is_challan_generated;
    
    @Column(name = "image_name")
    private String image_name;
    
    @Column(name = "location")
    private String location;

    @Column(name = "invalid_timestamp")
    private Timestamp invalid_timestamp;

//    @Transient
//    private List<ChallanReasonMaster> violationCharges = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getVehicle_no() {
        return vehicle_no;
    }

    public void setVehicle_no(String vehicle_no) {
        this.vehicle_no = vehicle_no;
    }

    public String getViolation_type() {
        return violation_type;
    }

    public void setViolation_type(String violation_type) {
        this.violation_type = violation_type;
    }

    public Timestamp getEntry_timestamp() {
        return entry_timestamp;
    }

    public void setEntry_timestamp(Timestamp entry_timestamp) {
        this.entry_timestamp = entry_timestamp;
    }

    public Integer getNum_images() {
        return num_images;
    }

    public void setNum_images(Integer num_images) {
        this.num_images = num_images;
    }

    public String getImage_type() {
        return image_type;
    }

    public void setImage_type(String image_type) {
        this.image_type = image_type;
    }

    public String getDevice_serial() {
        return device_serial;
    }

    public void setDevice_serial(String device_serial) {
        this.device_serial = device_serial;
    }

    public Integer getSpeed_limit() {
        return speed_limit;
    }

    public void setSpeed_limit(Integer speed_limit) {
        this.speed_limit = speed_limit;
    }

    public Integer getGate_id() {
        return gate_id;
    }

    public void setGate_id(Integer gate_id) {
        this.gate_id = gate_id;
    }

    public Integer getServer_id() {
        return server_id;
    }

    public void setServer_id(Integer server_id) {
        this.server_id = server_id;
    }

    public String getGate_name() {
        return gate_name;
    }

    public void setGate_name(String gate_name) {
        this.gate_name = gate_name;
    }

    public String getLane_name() {
        return lane_name;
    }

    public void setLane_name(String lane_name) {
        this.lane_name = lane_name;
    }

    public Long getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(Long user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public int getIs_challan_generated() {
        return is_challan_generated;
    }

    public void setIs_challan_generated(int is_challan_generated) {
        this.is_challan_generated = is_challan_generated;
    }

    public Timestamp getInvalid_timestamp() {
        return invalid_timestamp;
    }

    public void setInvalid_timestamp(Timestamp invalid_timestamp) {
        this.invalid_timestamp = invalid_timestamp;
    }

    

    public Timestamp getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public Integer getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Integer getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(Integer speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public String getLane() {
        return lane;
    }

    public void setLane(String lane) {
        this.lane = lane;
    }

    public int getExported() {
        return exported;
    }

    public void setExported(int exported) {
        this.exported = exported;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDg_code() {
        return dg_code;
    }

    public void setDg_code(String dg_code) {
        this.dg_code = dg_code;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    /*
     * public Integer getValidationStatus() { return validationStatus; }
     *
     * public void setValidationStatus(Integer validationStatus) {
     * this.validationStatus = validationStatus; }
     */

    public String getMade() {
        return made;
    }

    public void setMade(String made) {
        this.made = made;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }


    public String getImage_name() {
        return image_name;
    }

    public void setImage_name(String image_name) {
        this.image_name = image_name;
    }



    public long getTransit_id() {
        return transit_id;
    }

    public void setTransit_id(long transit_id) {
        this.transit_id = transit_id;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
```

I am new to jasper studio my table has many columns but in jasper report I used selective columns from table and used native query inside my repository but still I am not getting data into pdf report on console its showing null I used debug and try different aspect but unable to solve it.

Kindly help!

Comment: Remove the "fieldDescription" tags, jasper use them to know which field you like to access, if they are not present jasper will use fieldName which is what you expect

Comment: Sir I tried it already but its still giving me null let me edit the question

Comment: See I tried it the issue is same the pdf is generating but data is not showing

Comment: There is alot of code to test, what I see is that you pass as JRBEanCollectionDatasource to the report of a list of class Violation (even if in ViolationRepository you defined it as Object, I'm not sure why). Then in jasper report you have a subdatasource. Passing connection and sql?

Comment: So overall you have a logical problem, on main report (not in subdatasource) you have the JRBeanCollectionDatasource and in subreport you are trying to use a non existing connection? executing some sql??

Comment: I think you first need to understand that main datasource (that you pass from java) is in main report, while the subdatasource is something else that you need to define. Now I'm not sure what you are trying to do... but if you expect that main datasource (the beans) ends up automatically in subdatasource that is not the case.

Comment: To make you understand as constructed now, jasper will execute the detail band for every object that you have in your JRBeanCollectionDatasource and then in every band execute the jr:table with the subdatasource (where it should execute a sql but probably have no connection,)... is this what you want?

Comment: Ohk now I understand I will remove the subdata source and try to do it with main data source